# ASP.NET Session value not changing - TicTacToe app

Tags: asp.net

So, I'm trying to make a TicTacToe application, but the problem is the clickNo counter which should be counting clicks (after every click) is not being updated after the click. I've tried using if IsPostBack == false in Page Load, as someone suggested but the only thing that it accomplished is that a "O" randomly pops out.

```
{
        public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public int clickedByPlayerNo, clickNo;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Session["s1"] = clickNo;
            }

            public void buttonClicked(object Sender)
            {
                clickNo = (int)Session["s1"];

                if (Session["s1"] != null)
                {
                    clickNo = +1;

                    if (clickNo % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        clickedByPlayerNo = 2;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        clickedByPlayerNo = 1;
                    }



                    if (clickedByPlayerNo == 1)
                    {
                        ((Button)Sender).Text = "X";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((Button)Sender).Text = "O";
                    }
                    ((Button)Sender).Enabled = false;

                    Session["s1"] = clickNo;

                    checkWinner();
                }

                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Session expire");
                } 


            }

            public void checkWinner()
            {
                if (clickNo > 4)
                {

                    if (btn1.Text == btn2.Text && btn2.Text == btn3.Text && btn1.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn4.Text == btn5.Text && btn5.Text == btn6.Text && btn4.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn7.Text == btn8.Text && btn8.Text == btn9.Text && btn7.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn1.Text == btn4.Text && btn4.Text == btn7.Text && btn1.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn2.Text == btn5.Text && btn5.Text == btn8.Text && btn2.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn3.Text == btn6.Text && btn6.Text == btn9.Text && btn3.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn1.Text == btn5.Text && btn5.Text == btn9.Text && btn1.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (btn3.Text == btn5.Text && btn5.Text == btn7.Text && btn3.Text != "")
                    {
                        displayWinner();
                    }
                    else if (clickNo == 9)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Game Draw");

                        clearWindow();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Response.Write("Session expire"); 
                    } 
                }
            }

            public void displayWinner()
            {
                if (clickedByPlayerNo == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("Winner is A");
                }
                else
                    Response.Write("Winner is B");

                clearWindow();
            }

            public void clearWindow()
            {
                btn1.Text = "";
                btn1.Enabled = false;
                btn2.Text = "";
                btn2.Enabled = false;
                btn3.Text = "";
                btn3.Enabled = false;
                btn4.Text = "";
                btn4.Enabled = false;
                btn5.Text = "";
                btn5.Enabled = false;
                btn6.Text = "";
                btn6.Enabled = false;
                btn7.Text = "";
                btn7.Enabled = false;
                btn8.Text = "";
                btn8.Enabled = false;
                btn9.Text = "";
                btn9.Enabled = false;
            }


            protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }

            protected void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                buttonClicked(sender);
            }
        }
    }
```

My sincerest thanks to Red, I've been searching the net and looking at the monitor for 10 hours straight. Here's the updated part of the code:

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int clickedByPlayerNo, clickNo;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["s1"] = "-1";
        }
    }

    public void buttonClicked(object Sender)
    {
        clickNo = Convert.ToInt32(Session["s1"]);

        if (Session["s1"] != null)
        {
            int someValue = clickNo + 1;

            if (clickNo % 2 == 0)
            {
                clickedByPlayerNo = 2;
            }

            else
            {
                clickedByPlayerNo = 1;
            }



            if (clickedByPlayerNo == 1)
            {
                ((Button)Sender).Text = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                ((Button)Sender).Text = "O";
            }
            ((Button)Sender).Enabled = false;
            Session["s1"] = someValue;
        }



        checkWinner();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at `Page_Load` method. Every time you have a `postback` posted by one of your buttons, `Page_Load` method is called. What you need to do is to fill the session variable only once at page load. Here is what I would do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["s1"] = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I've already tried using  if (!IsPostBack) and it didn't work.

Comment: See my updated code. Try to assign 0 to the session once page is loaded.